# Orientation of vectors when they are right handed coordinate system.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let {$u, v$} be an ordered basis for $R^2$.
Prove that $O \begin{pmatrix} u\\v \end{pmatrix}=1$ iff {$u, v$} forms a right handed coordinate system.

I think I have to use the definition $O \begin{pmatrix} u\\v \end{pmatrix}= \frac{det \begin{pmatrix} u\\v \end{pmatrix}}{| det  \begin{pmatrix} u\\v \end{pmatrix}| }$
and it's iff I have to show both sides.
I tried several ways but couldn't get any trivial answer...

[ADDITION]
I solve it!

Comment: Part of the answer depends on your class's definition of "right handed coordinate system." Would you mind providing it? Also, a hint: the determinant of a matrix is the signed area of the parallelogram spanned by the columns of the matrix. Perhaps you can make use of that geometric insight.

Comment: $O$ = $\pm 1$. When is it positive?

Comment: I solved (->) direction, so now I'm trying to solve (<-) direction. Since $(v_1,v_2)=(u_1 \cos \theta - u_2 \sin \theta, u_1 \sin\theta+u_2\cos\theta)$ by the definition of rotation, we get $det \begin{pmatrix} u\\v \end{pmatrix}=(u_1 ^2+u_2 ^2)\sin\theta$. I stuck here.

Comment: What is your definition of right handed coordinate system? Can you say what the sign of $\sin \theta$ is?

Answer (score 1):

One of possible solutions:

1. Adding a multiple of one basis vector to another does not change the handedness. This can be seen geometrically, and also follows from the fact that $(\vec u,\vec v+t\vec u)$, $t\in\mathbb R$, is a continuous path within the set of bases.
2. Reversing  the order of vectors changes *both* the handedness and the sign of the determinant.
3. Reversing the direction of a basis vector changes *both* the handedness and the sign of the  determinant.
4. Using 1-2-3, the matrix $\begin{pmatrix}u\\v \end{pmatrix}$ can be transformed to the identity matrix. It has positive determinant, and yields a right-handed basis. $\Box$